# Hibernate Validator for forms: how to validate very similar DTO's

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am developing an Spring application using Hibernate Validator for the form validation. I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
public class RegisterUserDTO {


    @Size(min=3)
    private String inputName;

    @Email
    private String inputEmail;

    @Size(min=3)
    private String inputPassword;

    [...]

}
```

Where `inputPassword` is required. Somewhere else, I need to use the same input parameters, but the validations is slightly different:

```
public class RegisterUserDTO {


    @Size(min=3)
    private String inputName;

    @Email
    private String inputEmail;

    //@Size(min=3)
    private String inputPassword;

    [...]

}
```

`inputPassword` is not required.

How can I use the same DTO for both scenarios ? 
If this is not possible, what is the cleanest way to solve this situation ?

PS_ The following example uses the DTO in a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(ModelMap model, @Valid RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO, BindingResult result) {
    String template = "/path/to/addUser";
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        User user = new User(registerUserDTO.getInputName(), registerUserDTO.getInputPassword(), registerUserDTO.getInputEmail());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("errors", result.getFieldErrors());
    } else {
        User user = userService.insertUser(registerUserDTO.getInputEmail(), registerUserDTO.getInputName(), registerUserDTO.getInputPassword());
        template = "redirect:/path/to/edit/users/" + user.getId();
    }

    return template;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for validation groups.

Comment: @chrylis it might be the case. Do you have a link ?

Comment: @Tk421 Check this link for Spring MVC validation group: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is :

```
public class RegisterUserDTO {


    @Size(min=3)
    private String inputName;

    @Email
    private String inputEmail;


    private String inputPassword;


}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(ModelMap model, @Valid RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO, BindingResult result) {
        String template = "/path/to/addUser";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            User user = new User(registerUserDTO.getInputName(), registerUserDTO.getInputPassword(), registerUserDTO.getInputEmail());
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("errors", result.getFieldErrors());
            return template;
        } 
//when inputPassword is required add your test
if(your condition){
        FieldError error = new FieldError("registerUserDTO","inputPassword","Your message...");
        result.addError(error);
        return template;
}
User user = userService.insertUser(registerUserDTO.getInputEmail(), registerUserDTO.getInputName(), registerUserDTO.getInputPassword());
template = "redirect:/path/to/edit/users/" + user.getId();   
return template;
}
```

Comment: It looks a bit of work around :). Validation Groups looks better option, but I have not found the magic formula yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hibernate-validate `group`, such as:

```
public class ACValidTestVO {
@NotEmpty(message = "{ACValidTestVO.acId.notempty}", groups = {PrimaryKeyGroup.class})
private String acId;
@NotBlank(message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlVarchar.notblank}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
@Length(min = 1, max = 255, message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlVarchar.length}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
private String mysqlVarchar;//字符串
@NotEmpty(message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlChar.notempty}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
private String mysqlChar;//字符
@NotEmpty(message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlBlob.notempty}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
private String mysqlBlob;//二进制大对象
private String mysqlText;//文本
@Min(value = -2147483648, message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlInt.min}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
@Max(value = 2147483647, message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlInt.max}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
private String mysqlInt;//整形
private String mysqlTinyint;//小整形
private String mysqlSmallint;//短整形
private String mysqlMediumint;//中整形
private String mysqlBigint;//大整形
private String mysqlBit;//比特
@Digits(integer = 2, fraction = 2, message = "{ACValidTestVO.mysqlFloat.digits}", groups = {EntityGroup.class})
private String mysqlFloat;//浮点型
private String mysqlDouble;//双精度型
private String mysqlDecimal;//小数
private String mysqlBoolean;//布尔型
private String mysqlDate;//日期
private String mysqlTime;//时间
private String mysqlDatetime;//日期时间
private String mysqlTimestamp;//时间戳
private String mysqlYear;//年
```

}

so, different controller can use different group to validate, for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/save")
public ACResponseMsg save(@Validated({EntityGroup.class}) @RequestBody ACValidTestVO vo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ACResponseMsg msg = new ACResponseMsg();
    try {
        dataService.save(vo);
        msg.errcode = ACErrorMsg.CALL_SUCCESS.errcode;
        msg.errmsg = ACErrorMsg.CALL_SUCCESS.errmsg;
    } catch (ACServiceException e) {
        msg = e.getAcErrorMsg().toResponseMsg();
    } catch (ACDaoException e) {
        msg = e.getAcErrorMsg().toResponseMsg();
    } catch (ACRuntimeException e) {
        msg = e.getAcErrorMsg().toResponseMsg();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

that will be good, can solve you problem~~